# Interesting reverse of coding interview question

Tags: decode, encode

This is a popular interview question:

Given an encoded string, return its decoded string.

The encoding rule is: k[encoded_string], where the encoded_string inside the square brackets is being repeated exactly k times. Note that k is guaranteed to be a positive integer.

```
Input: s = "3[a]2[bc]"
Output: "aaabcbc"
```

which can be solved through smart use of stack.

I was thinking about the reverse: given a decoded string, can you find the **optimally encoded** string?

i.e.

```
Input: s = "aaabcbc"
Output: "3[a]2[bc]"
```

I have a feeling that this may be much harder than the previous one case you will have to keep track of each running substring.

Or is there an easy of doing it?

Comment: The answer may be not so obvious, e.g. should `abbabb` be `a2[b]a2[b]` or `2[abb]`? And this is a matter of [_optimal encoding_](https://www.google.com/search?q=optimal+encoding).

Comment: But "3[a]1[b]1[c]1[b]1[c]" gives the same output so is it possible ? I mean you can only find the possible outcomes because obviously there can be more than one answer .

Comment: I'm the author, and I voted to close it. you guys are right!

Comment: @Savrona That's correct, and for each possible encoding algorithm there exist data which get longer when encoded with that algorithm. But the aim of encoding is usually to make data shorter, and this is the difficulty: to encode optimally

Answer (score 0):

You could get creative with regular expressions and delegate the heavy lifting to the regular expression engine.

Here's a JavaScript example:

```js
const d = "aaabcbc";

const e = d.replaceAll(/(.+)\1+/g, (a, b) => `${a.length / b.length}[${b}]`);

console.log(e);
```